# How to open window and get response from submit when loggin in

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm currently working on login my user to his gmail, facebook, etc. account.
When the user clicks on the button, I create a uri with for example: 'https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id....redirect_uri=''....'

I think I need to have a window.open to display for example the gmail login page. There the user signs in and is then redirected to the initial page of my website.
But I would need to get the response from the login submission (as I need to send this response to my back end that he can update user).

But I don't know how to get the response from the login submission.
=> Do I need to set up sockets? or is there any simpler way?

On react native, there is authSession that does the job: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session#example 
but I didn't find any similar solution for reactjs.

Thanks for your help!

```
const setOAuthUrl = providerName => {
    // We get the current network data
    const network = networks[providerName];

    // We set the oAuthUrl with client id and redirect uri
    let oAuthUrl = `${network.oauth_url}?client_id=${
        network.client_id
    }&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        'http://localhost:3000/profile/network'
    )}`;

    // We add the params
    network.params.forEach(param => {
        oAuthUrl += `&${param}`;
    });
    return oAuthUrl;
};

const authUserToTheProvider = providerName => {
    // Here is don't know what to do
    window.open(setOAuthUrl(providerName));
};

const Network = ({ t }) => (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <HeadingSecondary text={t('network_edit.title_network')} />
        {Object.keys(networks).map(providerName => (
            <div key={providerName} className={styles.networkWrapper}>
                <NetworkButton
                    providerName={providerName}
                    onClick={() => authUserToTheProvider(providerName)}
                />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);

Network.propTypes = {
    t: func.isRequired
};

export default Network;
```

Comment: In the browser there is no such concept as windows. The page consist of a single DOM which react can modify according to the current application state. What you need to do is to modify your application state so that react knows it should render a login form. You also need a component that knows how to render a login form. You do not need sockets, you can simply do that with async requests using e.g. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Hi trixn, thanks for your feedback


Actually, I'm not having a usual login form issue here. 
I would like to show the usual google or facebook login system in a pop up or in another window to make my user signs in and then redirect them to my website. 
But I would like to get the response from their sign in (whether it succeed or failed) to send it back to my API.

A bit like this one but for any social network (pinterest, weibo, wordpress, etc.) so more generic: https://jsfiddle.net/nkd50mh3/

But i don't know how to keep tracking the google (or any other) sign in call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that this works is:

1. Your app redirects the user's browser to the Identity Provider (IdP) with your unique key
2. User Logs in to the IdP and authorises your app
3. IdP redirects the user back to a callback page on your app, with the authorisation code
4. React stores the authorisation code and sends it in the header of all future requests
5. The backend of your app will receive this authorisation code and validate it directly with the IdP

It can get a bit fiddly on a SPA, and I recommend using Auth0 to centralise the process and give the user a better experience.

see: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react

Within Auth0 you can add [multiple Identity Providers](https://auth0.com/docs/identityproviders), and you can configure [hooks](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks) and code snippets when a user authenticates. Also [Role Based Access](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension/v2) if you want.